# Lumberjack log DDLogInfo showing up as WARNING in console

Tags: ios, cocoa, logging, console, cocoalumberjack

I am using Lumberjack as my logging framework.

I have this definition…

```
#ifdef DEBUG
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG;
#else
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_WARN;
#endif
```

and this is my log statement…

```
DDLogInfo(@"Starting");
```

However when I look at the Console.app it shows this message as a WARNING instead of INFO like ASL can show.  Is there something else that I need to do?

This does allow the statement to not be logged when not in DEBUG mode, so that is working as advertised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. 
The DDASLLogger map the Debug to ASL's Warning level, Info to Error etc.
Thats because by default, ASL will filter Notice level and above.

*(In case DDLogInfo prints Warning, then you are using an older version of CocoaLumberjack)*

[Apple System Log documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/asl.3.html) says:

> The default filter mask is ASL_FILTER_MASK_UPTO(ASL_LEVEL_NOTICE). 
>   This means that by default, and in the absence of remote-control changes
>   (described below), ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG and ASL_LEVEL_INFO priority level messages
>   are not sent to the server.

You could try and write your own custom ASL logger.
But I suggest that you will add a custom formatter to the ASL logger that will add the actual log level (faster approache).